# How to add a challenge header in a forbidden_view using pyramid?

Tags: python, http, pyramid, basic-authentication

When I define a forbidden view using `@forbidden_view_config` I want to challenge the client for user and password. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply add the challenge to the response. Other than that the forbidden view is just like any other (exception) view.

```
@forbidden_view_config(renderer='json')
def unauthenticated_forbidden_view(exc, request):
    request.response.status_code = 401
    request.response.www_authenticate = 'Bearer'
    return {'error': 'auth_required'}
```

Comment: Hi, I added the forbidden view with the same exact code but when I go to http://local_host:6543/private I just get the jason {"error": "auth_required"}.  But it does not challenge the client!!!

Comment: Your client probably doesn't support a Bearer token challenge. Use the appropriate challenge for your authentication scheme. For example `'Basic realm="foobar"'`.